# Selection function and set-valued maps

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i've learned a little bit about topology and i got stuck with this definition.
Given $X, Y$ topological space. Define $F:X\to Y$ set valued maps from $X$ to $Y$. $G:X\to Y$ can be said contained in $F$ if $G(x)\subset F(x),\forall x\in X$. Define $f:X\to Y$, $f$ is called selection of $F$ if $f(x)\in F(x),\forall x\in X$. My question is, is it true that $f$ which is selection of $F$ is also contained in $F$?maybe it sounds stupid but i still don't understand about this problem, thank you!

Comment: By "set valued map $F:X \rightarrow Y$" do you mean a map from the power set of $X$ to the power set of $Y$?

Comment: Yes, i mean that

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. But yes, if you allow some abuse of language and notation.

The reason that the answer is negative is that $f\colon X\to Y$ is not the same "type" as $F\colon X\to\mathcal P(Y)$ (that is, a set-valued function). It is not always that $y\in Y$ is also a subset of $Y$, although this can certainly happen (nevertheless, even in that case, we're not guaranteed that a selection is itself a set-valued function).

But, and that's quite a hefty but, sometimes people purposefully "confuse" $y$ with $\{y\}$.<sup>1</sup> This is sometimes convenient for this exact reason. Now, if you do decide to confuse $y$ and $\{y\}$, then a selection is indeed contained in the function it selects from, since $f(x)\in F(x)$ if and only if $\{f(x)\}\subseteq F(x)$.

Still, this is something I would expect to be mentioned explicitly, or at least remarked when making this sort of abuse for the first time. So formally the answer is no, but in practice the answer is "sometimes yes, depends on the author".

---

1. For example, my algebraic topology professor declared just that on the very first lecture.

Comment: Ok, I understand your statement, thanks!